# Make JDA Discord Bot write a message with a delay

Tags: bots, delay, discord, discord-jda

I'm currently trying to make my JDA Bot write a message if it leaves a voice channel. Then 3 seconds after the message is sent it should follow with another message.

I've already tried to do it with the RestAction but I could only figure out how to delete a message with delay.

The code would look something like this :

```java
channel.sendMessage("You told me to leave, so I left"); //I shortened the message command here

//Then with a delay of 3 seconds it should do this
channel.sendMessage("That was mean");
```

I hope someone will be able to help me out here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every RestAction has a [`queueAfter(long, TimeUnit)`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html#queueAfter(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) which can be used to delay it:

```java
channel.sendMessage("Hello").queueAfter(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```